# Can't change frame cursor to custom cursor

Tags: swing, scala

I can change the cursor to one from the system, but cannot make the one i created to be displayd, and i have absolutely no idea what am i doing wrong, it does not throw to me any exception whatsoever. This is my code:

```
class CustomWin extends MainFrame{

title = "SdC2 Launcher"
cursor = defineCursor
iconImage = defineIcon
visible = true

contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical){
  contents += new Label("Label de prueba")
  contents += new Label("Label de prueba")
  val lab = new Label("Label de prueba")
  lab cursor = defineCursor
  contents += lab
}

preferredSize = new Dimension(300,300)
centerOnScreen
pack
open

private val defineCursor = {
  val hotspot = new Point(0, 0)
   //val image = ImageIO.read(new File("images/cursor.png"))
  val image = new ImageIcon("/images/cursor2.gif")
  toolkit.createCustomCursor(image.getImage(), hotspot, "MainCursor")
}

private val defineIcon: Image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/cursor.png")).getImage()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are running into initialization order issues. Namely, at the time you call `cursor = defineCursor` and `lab cursor = defineCursor`, `defineCursor` is still `null`. You should initialize `val`s before the places in the constructor code where they are used.

Comment: Man, that was it! It worked like a charm. Thanks buddy, should i have declared them like methods not vals.

Comment: If you make them methods, `defineCursor` will be called two times in this case (which may not be a problem for you). You can also use `lazy val` to make sure it's called only once at the point where it's first used.